# .NET MAUI on jetbrains Rider: different statements in MauiProgram.cs when different launch configurations

Tags: xamarin, testing, configuration, maui, rider

I want to test my .NET Maui app, and for that, I use the Shiny.xunit.runners.maui library ([github project](https://github.com/shinyorg/xunit-maui)).
This library requires some particular statements in the MauiProgram class, which replace the call to `builder.UseMauiApp<App>()`. Here is my MauiProgram class:

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .UseDevExpress()
            .UseFluentMauiIcons()
            .UseFluentFilledMauiIcons()
            .UseMaterialMauiIcons()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                fonts.AddFont("Roboto-Medium.ttf", "Roboto Medium");
                fonts.AddFont("Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf", "Roboto Medium Italic");
            });


        //either run the tests
        builder.ConfigureTests(new TestOptions
            {
                Assemblies =
                {
                    typeof(MauiProgram).Assembly
                }
            })
            .UseVisualRunner();

        //or the app
        //builder.UseMauiApp<App>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<Datas>();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

It works as is, but I can't modify the class each time I change of configuration, so I need a way to use Rider (or visual studio) in a way that the each launch configuration will trigger the use of the corresponding group of statements.

But I did not manage to do this, I tried to modify some environment variables, but in vain, I can't get the environment variables from the MauiProgram class, and I presume it is because my app only runs on an android target, so it would get my device's environment variables (to be confirmed).

Do you see some trick to make my MauiProgram aware of which configuration launching it is run with?

thank you